# SAS delete row when a column is non numeric

Tags: sas

I have this dataset student in SAS and I planned to delete the records(rows) where grade is non numeric. I tried the following code and it didnt worked. I tried 'if grade=. then delete;' as well and it still didnt work. I do not want to replace the values and I just want to delete the row. Any ideas on this?

```
data student;
infile datalines firstobs=2 dsd truncover; 
input student$ class$ grade; 
datalines;
student, class, grade 
Jansen, Brave, A
Yassin, Brave, 70
Benison, Brave, 67
Yan Jin, Brave, E
James, Hero, 90 
Michelle, Hero, 89
Hiroku, Hero, C 
Misoku, Hero, 93
;
run; 

data student_cleaned; 
set work.student; 
if not (anyalpha(grade)) then delete; 
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first step you read in grade as numeric. This means SAS will already have removed any characters from that data set. Read it in as character and then you can do the second step. Add a $ after grade to read it in as a character value.

Literally a one character change ;)

```
data student;
infile datalines firstobs=2 dsd truncover; 
input student$ class$ grade $; 
datalines;
student, class, grade 
Jansen, Brave, A
Yassin, Brave, 70
Benison, Brave, 67
Yan Jin, Brave, E
James, Hero, 90 
Michelle, Hero, 89
Hiroku, Hero, C 
Misoku, Hero, 93
;
run; 

data student_cleaned; 
set work.student; 
if anyalpha(grade) then delete; 
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You already read GRADE as a numeric variable.  The single letter codes like A or E will be mapped to the corresponding special missing values like .A or .E. Any other text will be mapped to regular missing.

You can use the MISSING() function to test for any of those.

```
if missing(grade) then delete;
```

Comment: Thank you Tom. I always thought missing() is used when there is really no missing values. Got it now!

Comment: if i have a column named 'student.grade' and i tried if missing('student.grade'n) then delete; it cant work. may i know how could i solve it?

Comment: If 'student.grade'n is a character variable then values like  'A' or 'B' is not considered missing by the missing() function. Note that you have to have the VALIDVARNAME option set to ANY to be able to use variable names with periods in them.